# Highlight text javascript for google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, highlight

i am currently writing a google chrome extension that should highlight some text of a webpage.
I have a list of keywords and i want to mark all words equal to one of the keyword list elements.

Let us say for example i use:

```
var text=document.getElementById("p0003");
```

to get some text.
Now i have the list:

```
var highlightList=["such", "a", "nice", "day"]
```

How can i highlight all words in text that equal to a element of my highlightList?

Comment: Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and standard DOM processing or an existing library like `mark.js`.

Comment: I do have a content script, that already get the text. But how can i write back to the back from it?

Comment: There's no need to "write back to the back from it". You can follow the advice I gave as is.

Comment: You can also [easily find](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+chrome+extension+highlight+words) other examples and similar existing extensions.

Comment: I already checked them. It seems like most of them use the window selection in order to highlight. But as i do not select text in a window i do not know how to start it

Comment: I tried it out the last days and it works very nicely! Thanks! I do have one more question concerning the MIT-licence. I am new to all this as you might have noticed, so i wonder if i can use mark.js within a product I am maybe going to sell anytime in the far future..   As I understood MIT-licence it is allowed and you can just do whatever you want with the code. Is that right? do you know more about it?

Comment: Yes, see [tldrlegal](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mit-license).

Comment: @wOxxOm see my new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395471/mark-js-keep-marking-permanently if you feel like.