# Mark.js keep marking permanently?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, highlight

i am currently using mark.js for a google chrome extension to highlight some text on a web page.

Now whenever i refresh the page or do a right click all my marking is lost.

Is there a way to keep that marking? As far as i see mark.js does not change the DOM.
I would like to mark the text but also be able e.g. when i print that page or save it as a pdf, to maintain the highlighting i did..

That is the way i mark. it is pretty much the same as instructed on https://markjs.io/:

```
function mark(text, label){
var paragraphs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('description-line'));
switch(label){
        case "strAdv":
            for(var elem of paragraphs) { // loop through each element in paragraphs array
                 var instance=new Mark(elem);
                 instance.mark(text, {className: "strAdv",separateWordSearch:false});

             }
             break;
....
```

strAdv.css:

```
/*CSS to define diferent marking classes*/
.strAdv {
padding: 0;
background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to overcome that problem.
Just store the text items you want to mark and mark them again every time a page gets refreshed.